# Latest version of the app is ready for sale in App Store but after update the app is not really updated

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

What do I mean?

My app was approved and since saturday is ready for sale. Some of my customers **can see** an update in app store and then they **do** an update. After update is completed, the open button appears and... after app is opened we can see that it is previous version;)

Why?;)

It happens really often.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you directly archive your application for publish instead of 'clean and build' it in the release option.

If you directly archive the app, there is a change it could take the previous version's release instead of doing the clean and build.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: How to clean and build in release option?

Comment: Right click on your project and rebuild the solution. Attached the picture